# Getting Generics information in ASM bytecode library

Tags: java, generics, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM library to parse Java bytecode, now I am trying to parse a method, and I am on good way. But I am facing bit issue in parsing the method's parameters and convert it into equivalent Java source code especially if paramter is of type Generic List, ArrayList, Set etc. Consider this method visitor code:

```
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
        String arg3, String[] arg4)
{
     System.out.println("Method params: " + arg2);
}
```

just prints:

```
(Ljava/util/List;)V
```

for this method parameter:

```
List<String> foo;
```

As you can see I have lost all of the things which comes between `<` and `>`. I am aware of erasure for generics types.

But I need this information to know what type of List is not just `java/util/List`. Is there anyway to get this information using ASM library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASM has a [SignatureVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/signature/SignatureVisitor.html) which you can use to visit type signatures. those contain the generics info of class, methods and fields visited.

you can find more info about it in the [asm guide](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf), under section 4.1 - generics

Comment: If anyone interested the link for asm guide is changed. https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf